# MS Word: Adding a line before and after text

Tags: microsoft-word

How could I add a line before and after a piece of text in Word, like in this image with the word 
["Education"](http://postimg.org/image/o1nj84p1l/):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't mention the version of Word, I'll try and keep this general.  I'm using Word 2013 for the record.

- Draw a line (like put in a bunch of dashes and hit enter to let Word convert it to a border line).
- Inset a TextBox object.
- Enter desired text in the textbox.
- Center the text in the text box, and adjust the Textbox to the size you want.
- Adjust the layout of the TextBox to be "In front of text".
- Format the TextBox shape and chang ehte Shape Outlooine to "No outline".
- Drag the TextBox in front of the line to where you want it.

Additionally you can use advanced Layout->Position options to center it horizontally on the page, etc.

Result (with no additional formatting, colouring, etc.):

[image]

Alternatively:

- Type in regular text and center it.
- Insert a Line shape, and draw it on one side of the text.
- Copy the line nad paste it on the other side of the text.
- Hold Ctrl and click to select each of the lines.
- Use the shape formatting in Word and "Align Middle" to line them up vertically.
- "Group" them.
- "Align Center" to center the now group lines in the center of the page.

Result:

[image]

Comment: No problem, you could also combine the above by using a TextBox shape with the drawn line shapes, and then group the three "Shapes" together so you can move them as one. :)