# What's a good way to achieve this textbox title effect in Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

In Word 2016 what's the correct way to get a textbox with title on top border like the following?

[image]

I found this exact question in this forum http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/25236-text-box-title-top-border-effect.html
but it was for Office 2013 and the solution implied creating 2 boxes and superimposing one above the other.

Is there a better (perhaps native?) way to do this with Word 2016?

Maybe this other question on SuperUser can be of inspiration?
 [MS Word: Adding a line before and after text](https://superuser.com/questions/722557/ms-word-adding-a-line-before-and-after-text)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a frame object. It's a bit fiddly, and personally I'd prefer the 'two box' solution you mention, but here's an alternative for you.

1. Enable the 'Developer' tab in the ribbon. If you're not sure how to do this, read the [Microsoft how-to guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb608625.aspx).
2. On the Ribbon, select **Developer**, then the **Legacy Tools** icon (in the 'Controls' area), then the **More Controls** button in the bottom right of the ActiveX Controls section.

[image: The More Controls icon]

3. Scroll down and select **Microsoft Forms 2.0 Frame**.
4. You'll get a blank frame like this with a Properties menu. You'll need to customise the Properties box to achieve the format you want.

[image: Blank Frame]

5. Edit properties as follows:

   - Back Colour: White
   - Border Colour: Red (whichever colour red you want)
   - Special Effect: 0 - fmSpecialEffectFlat
   - Border Style: 1 - fmBorderStyleSingle
   - Caption: Core Capabilities
   - Font: Georgia (or whatever font you want)
   - Fore Colour: Red (as before)

[image: Edited frame]